# Can't get Kovan testnet from Faucets.chain.link

Tags: solidity, ether, etherscan, testnets, kovan

I'm trying to get the `ETH -> USD` price from ChainLink but it's code requires the Kaven testnet.
But the problem is that the https://faucets.chain.link website isn't working correctly and it sends the testnet to random public keys after I enable the `Send Request` button by changing its code :
[image]

My public key is : 0x8D50b6840C0cEb89e302aC2b9d951d0e16b4b8dF

But it sends the testnet to other accounts :

[image]

I already tried using VPN and changing the IP address and other stuffs but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to click 'Connect wallet' button on top right of the page and give permission to access to your wallet. Then you'll see the textbox called 'Wallet address' will fill itself with your address. At that point, you can complete the CAPTCHA and request your ETH and LINK.

IMPORTANT: You must to select on 'Network' dropdown the testnet on which  you would to have the coins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kovan is deprecated. If you need any free Goerli testETH, Alchemy runs this one - https://goerlifaucet.com. You can get more every day, although I find it enough for my testnet needs.

For context, Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running bc of the recent Ethereum Merge. All others including Ropsten, Rinkeby and Kovan have been deprecated.